# Wordpress admin-ajax.php 400

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange and frustrating behaviour of wordpress admin-ajax.php file, when i make an ajax request it returns 400 error bad request.

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
var true_posts = '<?php echo serialize($wp_query->query_vars); ?>'; 
var current_page = <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>;
var max_pages = '<?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>';
jQuery(function($){
                $('#true_loadmore').click(function(){
                    $(this).text('Loading...');
                    var data = {
                        'action': 'loadmore',
                        'query': true_posts,
                        'page' : current_page
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url:ajaxurl,
                        data:data,
                        type:'POST',
                        success:function(data){
                            if( data ) { 
                                $('#true_loadmore').text('View more recent Posts').before(data);
                                current_page++;
                                if (current_page == max_pages) $("#true_loadmore").remove();
                            } else {
                                $('#true_loadmore').remove();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

my functions.php .

```
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'true_load_posts');

function true_load_posts(){

    $args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    query_posts( $args );
    if( have_posts() ) :

        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

    endif;
    die();
}
```

And I got 400 error . 
  Someone could help me to please? thank you.

Comment: Edit your post, don't chuck code blocks in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

the problem should be the action in your sending data.

The 'action' value must correspond to the function name in the php side (and in the add_action method ).

```
var data = {
    'action': 'true_load_posts',    //instead of 'loadmore'
    'query': true_posts,
    'page' : current_page
};
```

Hope this help.

Comment: it didn't help :(
i thought that action must be loadmore because `wp_ajax_loadmore`

Comment: You're right, I am sorry. How did you declare the js file?

Comment: i add js file with script tag in index.php

Comment: I suggest you, then, to enqueue the script and localize it. I found a simple guide where you can find what I told you: https://webkul.com/blog/using-ajax-wordpress/ (first code).